# How to deploy a .NET core console app to Azure Kubernetes Service?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, console-application

I have a .NET core console application to crawl a database periodically at certain intervals. I have dockerized it and have been able to run the docker image successfully from my local system. My ultimate objective is to deploy it from AKS. So I have pushed the aforementioned image to Azure Container Registry also. Please help me figure out the next steps on how to deploy the image from ACR into AKS.

The Dockerfile used to create the docker image :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0
COPY bin/Release/net5.0/publish/ App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<app_name>.dll"]
```

The YAML file used to deploy to AKS :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
      Process: <app_name>
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: <app_name>
    name: <app_name>
  spec:
    selector:
      app: <app_name>
  status:    
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    annotations:
      Process: <app_name>
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      app: <app_name>
    name: <app_name>
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: <app_name>
    strategy: {}
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app: <app_name>
      spec:
        containers:
        - env:
          image: "<acr_name>.azurecr.io/<image_name>:<version_tag>"
          name: <app_name>          
          resources: {}
        restartPolicy: Always
  status: {}
kind: List
metadata: {}
```

I am relatively new to Docker technologies, and I am unsure whether this is the proper way to deploy .NET console apps to AKS or if this is the proper YAML configuration for a console app o deploy it to AKS. Please help me in figuring this out. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a reference doc from Microsoft's documentation and then ask a more specific question.

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/containerized-lifecycle/design-develop-containerized-apps/build-aspnet-core-applications-linux-containers-aks-kubernetes#push-the-image-into-the-azure-acr

Console App would be simpler than a web app. You will need to take out the port and service configs.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: console-app
  labels:
    app: console-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: console-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: console-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: console-app
          image: exploredocker.azurecr.io/console-app:v1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Comment: What I am specifically looking for, as mentioned in the title itself, is help with deploying console apps to AKS, not WebApps or WebAPIs. The link you provided, unfortunately, does not help me in that regard. If you can find anything about deployment of .NET core console apps to AKS, please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: Deployment is kubernetes would look exactly the same except you won't need those environment vars. If your app has wait built-in then the deployment is fine, however, if you want Kubernetes to run the job periodically, then you need to create a CronJob instead of a Deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to modify the docker file with the correct project path

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
# COPY *.sln .
COPY dotnet-app/*.csproj ./dotnet-app/
RUN dotnet restore dotnet-app

# copy everything else and build app
COPY dotnet-app/. ./dotnet-app/
WORKDIR /app/dotnet-app
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/dotnet-app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnet-app.dll"]
```

Here is a step by step instruction from the sample [repository](https://github.com/sajeetharan/docker-k8s-dotnetapp) i built

Comment: While it might help to modify the Dockerfile, I prefer to keep it simple as long as it works. As I have mentioned in the question, the Docker image runs locally and I am able to crawl the DB by running the Docker image. What I am really looking for is a way to deploy a console app to AKS, not an WebApp or an WebAPI. I think the problem is with the YAML config, or the process of deployment itself. Can you please help me out there?